# How do I generalize this Ecto/Elixir function?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've got the following, which applies a WHERE statement to an ecto query if `platform` exists.

```
  defp maybe_platform(queryable, false), do: queryable
  defp maybe_platform(queryable, platform) do
      queryable
      |> where([c], c.platform == ^platform)
  end
```

How can I generalise this code for any variable (instead of just `platform`)? (it's the `c.platform` bit I'm struggling with)

Comment: What should the generalized signature look like? Do you want something like `maybe_filter(queryable, field, value)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Ecto field` https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#field/2

Your function would look something like this

```
defp maybe_field(queryable, field_name, field_value) do
    queryable
    |> where([c], field(c, ^field_name) == ^field_value)
end
```

and then

```
(from m in MyModel)
|> maybe_field(:platform, "platform_name_or_variable")
|> maybe_field(:another_field, "some value")
|> maybe_field(:is_platform_enabled, true)
|> Repo.all
```

Comment: I think you're missing a clause for when the `field_value` is `false` returns `queryable`.

Comment: @AlexanderdeSousa I think false is also compared with. I checked in one of my repos passing true and false to a boolean field and it seemed to work as expected. Let me know if I'm mistaken

Answer (score 0):

You can use keywords as filter. Have a look at [Ecto.Query#where/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#where/3-keywords-example):

```
from(c in City, where: c.country == "Sweden")
from(c in City, where: [country: "Sweden"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ecto.Query.where/3` accepts keyword list as filters. Elixir keyword list is just a wrapper around Erlang lists of tuples of two elements each. That said, somewhat like that would do:

```
defp maybe_where(queryable, _param, false), do: queryable
defp maybe_where(queryable, param, value) do
  filters = [{param, value}]
  where(queryable, ^filters)
end
```